# robocopy error with ERROR 32 (0x00000020)

Tags: robocopy

I have two drives A and B. Using a python script I am creating some files in "A" drive and I am running a powerscript which copies all the files in the drive A to drive B in the interval of 1 sec.

I am getting this error in my powershell.

> 2015/03/10 23:55:35 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Time-Stamping Destination
>   File \x.x.x.x\share1\source\ Dummy_100.txt The process cannot access
>   the file because it is being used by another process. Waiting 30
>   seconds...

How will I overcome this error?

Answer (score 5):

if you want to skip this files you can use `/r:n` that `n` is times of tries
for example `/w:3 /r:5` will try 5 time every 3 seconds

Answer (score 3):

This happened is because the file is locked by running process. To fix this, download [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Then use Find>Find Handle or DLL, find out which process locked this file. Use 'taskkill' to kill that process in commandline. You will be fine.

Comment: I waited 30 seconds... then another 30 seconds... then the process eventually stopped interfering and moved on.

Comment: Add /f will let you kill without waiting.

Comment: But you don't want to kill the Server Agent in case that's what's hogged the file. Using /F is like using a sledge hammer. Waiting is better

Comment: robocopy has no /f , friends

Answer (score 2):

```
How will I overcome this error?
```

If backup is, what you got in mind, and you encounter in-use files frequently, you look into Volume Shadow Copies (VSS), which allow to copy files despite them being ‘in use’. It's not a product, but a windows technology used by various backup tool.

Sadly, it's not built into robocopy, but can be used in conjunction with it. See

➝ https://superuser.com/a/602833/75914

and especially:

➝ https://github.com/candera/shadowspawn

Answer (score 1):

It could be many reasons.

In my case, I was running a CMD script to copy from one server to another, a heap of SQL Server backups and transaction logs. I too had the same problem because it was trying to write into a log file that was *supposedly* opened by another process. It was not.

I ran many IP checks and Process ID checkers that I ran out of knowing what was hogging the log file. Event viewer said nothing.

I found out it was not even the log file that was being locked. I was able to delete it by logging into the server as a normal user with no admin privileges!

It was the backup files themselves by the SQL Server Agent. Like @Oseack said, there may have been the need to use **another tool** whilst the backup files themselves were still being used or locked by the SQL Server Agent.

The way I got around it was to force ROBOCOPY to wait.

> /W:5

did it.